# Dispatch function seems to run more than one time after I test on stand alone app expo-deeplink

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux, expo

It sounds so weird to me and I have no idea what's wrong here because everything is fine in a development environment. So the way app works are simple, user sign in, choose it's therapist then pay for it and after successful payment, booking is confirmed, but the problem is booking is being booked exactly 3 times in firebase real-time database no matter what and I don't know why... (in the development area all is fine and it's gonna book just once as the user requested)

**here's my code of booking:**

```
const bookingHandler = () => {
    Linking.openURL('http://www.medicalbookingapp.cloudsite.ir/sendPay.php');
  }

  const handler = (e) => handleOpenUrl(e.url);
  useEffect(() => {

    Linking.addEventListener('url', handler)

    return () => {
      Linking.removeEventListener('url', handler);

    }

  });

  const handleOpenUrl = useCallback((url) => {
    const route = url.replace(/.*?:\/\/\w*:\w*\/\W/g, '') // exp://.... --> ''
    const id = route.split('=')[1]

    if (id == 1) {
      handleDispatch();
      toggleModal();
    } else if (id == 0) {
      console.log('purchase failed...');
      toggleModal();
    }
  });

  const handleDispatch = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(
      BookingActions.addBooking(
        therapistId,
        therapistFirstName,
        therapistLastName,
        selected.title,
        moment(selectedDate).format("YYYY-MMM-DD"),
        selected.slots,
      )
    );

    dispatch(
      doctorActions.updateTherapists(therapistId, selected.slots, selectedDate, selected.title, selectedPlanIndex, selectedTimeIndex)
    );
    setBookingConfirm(true)
  })
```

**booking action:**

```
export const addBooking = (therapistId, therapistFirstName, therapistLastName, sessionTime, sessionDate, slotTaken) => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    let userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
    
    const confirmDate = moment(new Date()).format("ddd DD MMMM YYYY")

    const response = await fetch(
      `https://mymedicalbooking.firebaseio.com/bookings/${userId}.json`,
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          userId,
          therapistId,
          confirmDate,
          therapistFirstName,
          therapistLastName,
          sessionTime,
          sessionDate,
          slotTaken
        })
      }
    );

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Something went wrong!');
    }

    const resData = await response.json();
   
    dispatch({
      type: ADD_BOOKING,
      bookingData: {
        userId: userId,
        therapistId: therapistId,
        therapistFirstName: therapistFirstName,
        therapistLastName: therapistLastName,
        sessionTime: sessionTime,
        sessionDate: sessionDate
      }
    });
  };
};
```

**Booking reducer:**

```
const initialState = {
  bookings: [],
  userBookings: []
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_BOOKING:
      const newBooking = new Booking(
        action.bookingData.id,
        action.bookingData.therapistId,
        action.bookingData.therapistFirstName,
        action.bookingData.therapistLastName,
        action.bookingData.bookingdate
      );
      return {
        ...state,
        bookings: state.bookings.concat(newBooking)
      };
    case FETCH_BOOKING:
      const userBookings = action.userBookings;
      return {
        ...state,
        userBookings: userBookings
      };
  }

  return state;
};
```

also, I use expo, SDK 38, Firebase as a database.

I really need to solve this, please if you have any idea don't hesitate to leave a comment or answer all of them kindly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I commented out all deep linking functionality and test the result, it's all fine. so I think the problem is with the `eventListener` or how I implemented my deep linking code but I still don't figure out what's wrong with the code that does fine in expo and has a bug in stand-alone.

**UPDATE 2**

I tried to add dependency array as suggested but still I have same problem..

Comment: try to add empty dependency array to your `useEffect`, you may set to many event listeners because at every state/prop change effect run (default behavior without dependency array)

Comment: please check [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) and you must read the `note` section

Comment: @HagaiHarari Thanks for the suggestion, I tried that but no luck. same problem still exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**there is an issue in `expo-linking` which on the standalone detached android app: event url fires multiple times** [ISSUE](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2128)

I just wrapped my handling function in `lodash`'s debounce with 1000ms wait

install lodash like this

```
yarn add lodash
```

```
import _ from 'lodash';

const handleOpenUrl = _.debounce((event) => {
    // here is other logic
  },1000);
```

**here is your code**

just add an empty dependency array into `useEffect` and use `useCallback` like this

```js
useEffect(() => {
    Linking.addEventListener('url', handleOpenUrl)
    return () => {
      Linking.removeEventListener('url', handleOpenUrl);
    }

  },[]);  //like this []
```

```js
const handleOpenUrl = _.debounce((url) => {
    const route = url.replace(/.*?:\/\/\w*:\w*\/\W/g, '') // exp://.... --> ''
    const id = route.split('=')[1]

    if (id == 1) {
      handleDispatch();
      toggleModal();
    } else if (id == 0) {
      console.log('purchase failed...');
      toggleModal();
    }
  },1000); //like this []
```

```js
const handleDispatch = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(
      BookingActions.addBooking(
        therapistId,
        therapistFirstName,
        therapistLastName,
        selected.title,
        moment(selectedDate).format("YYYY-MMM-DD"),
        selected.slots,
      )
    );

    dispatch(
      doctorActions.updateTherapists(therapistId, selected.slots, selectedDate, selected.title, selectedPlanIndex, selectedTimeIndex)
    );
    setBookingConfirm(true)
  },[selected])
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer bro but if I add this dependency arrays I end up with another problem which is after come back to app from payment `selected` state data gone and my dispatch function returns undefined. how can I handle this then?

Comment: @EshgheCode you can add `selected` state in dependency array on `handleDispatch`. i have updated my answer

Comment: I manage my state and I have no problem with it anymore and as you suggested I do all the dependency arrays and it is working but not after i test the `apk` file again same thing happens and it booked to firebase 2 times.

Comment: Yes it is working and I do, sorry for being late.

Comment: Bro I meant its working on debug mode not in stand alone, I have the same problem still on apk file after I install it on a physical device - or emulator.